# How to force keeping mails with Dovecot/POP3?

Tags: pop3, dovecot

I want to get rid of POP3 to prevent mails being moved from the server to the computer with a client like Outlook/Thunderbird (the default behavior of this protocol). However, some "power users" want to keep the import feature in Gmail, which is POP3 only. Is it possible to set Dovecot in order to block the "deletion" ? I know that it's possible to do it by setting the clients but they're too heterogenous, I want to do it in the server side only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, horrible and disgusting but you could set each email immutable. SSH into the mail directory (eg. /var/spool/mail) and run the following command:
`for i in 'find .'; do chattr +i $i; done` (change the ' ' to backticks, I'm not sure how to escape them on this site).

Once you've finished with the POP3 shiz, rerun the command with -i.

Please note this will only protect any emails that existed when you ran the command.

Comment: intead of backticks you can use $(...) syntax
e.g. - `for i in $(find .); do chattr +i $i; done`